# System slowdown when laptop is charging/plugged in via usb-c

Tags: laptop, power-supply, usb-c

I have an HP Spectre x360 15-t running windows 10. When I connect to a usb-c charger rather than the proprietary charger, my system experiences noticeable slowdown. Navigating files in windows explorer is slower; opening new directories generally results in a brief display of "working on it" in the window. Switching tabs in a web browser has noticeable lag. These issues occur even if I ask the system to maximize performance. They do not occur while running on battery. I've tested this with a 60 watt charger, 65 watt charger, and 87 watt charger; I thought the wattage might be the source of the issue, because the proprietary charger is 135 watts. However, even the 87 watt charger, which is higher wattage than the built in battery, experiences these issues.

Comment: Just FYI, "even the 87 watt charger, which is higher wattage than the built in battery, experiences these issues." -- the battery capacity is measured in watt-hours where the charger is measured in watts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed a BIOS update and it seems to have fixed the issue! For reference, if anyone else is experiencing this, my BIOS was F.22 and now it is F.28.

Thank you to those who responded to my query.

Answer (score 0):

HP is [known](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3017182/usb-c-charging-universal-or-bust-we-plug-in-every-device-we-have-to-chase-the-dream.html) to play very nasty games with USB C, I wouldn't put it beyond them to put (or, more charitably, accidentally leave) a bug in the power driver for the notebook causing high I/O or CPU load which would produce the symptoms you described. There is nothing you can do aside from only using the USB C charger when the system is off/sleeping.